# Is it possible to override bracket operators in ruby like endpoint notations in math?

Tags: arrays, ruby, math, overriding, enumerable

Trying to implement something like this:

```
arr = (1..10)

arr[2,5] = [2,3,4,5]
arr(2,5] = [3,4,5]
arr[2,5) = [2,3,4]
arr(2,5) = [3,4]
```

Well, we need to override four bracket opreators: [], [), (], ()

Any ideas?

It's called "Including or excluding" in mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints

Comment: Although the link is useful, you should take the time to include that information within your question- it's not that difficult to explain. Also to override a method it has to exist in the first place. Only the `[]` exists for arrays, the other three `(]`,`[)` and `()` would have to be created. Not to mention implementing the syntactic sugar.

Comment: No, the syntax you propose is not something it's possible to make the Ruby parser understand.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is not possible with the current Ruby parser.

The slightly longer answer: You'd have to start by modifying [parse.y](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y) to support the syntax you propose and recompile Ruby. This is of course not a terrible practical approach, since you'd have to do that again for every new Ruby version. The saner approach would be to start a discussion on [ruby-core](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/ruby/ruby-core/index.shtml) to see if there is sufficient interest for this to be made part of the language (probably not tbh).

Answer (score 0):

Your wanted syntax is not valid for the Ruby parser, but it could be implemented in Ruby with the help of self-modifying code.

The source files need to be pre-processed. A simple regular expression can substitute your interval expressions with ordinary method syntax, i.e.

```
arr[2,5]   ->  interval_closed(arr,2,5)
arr(2,5]   ->  interval_left_open(arr,2,5)
arr[2,5)   ->  interval_right_open(arr,2,5)
arr(2,5)   ->  interval_open(arr,2,5)
```

The string holding the modified source can be evaluated and becomes part of the application just like a source file on the hard disk. (See [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval))

The usage of self-modifying code should be well justified.

- Is the added value worth the effort and the complications?
- Does the code have to be readable for other programmers?
- Is the preprocessing practical? E.g. will this syntax occur in one or a few isolated files, or be spread everywhere?